# How to convert a Binary Image to Grayscale and RGB using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on hair removal from skin lesion images. Is there any way to convert binary back to rgb?

Original Image:

[image]

Mask Image:

[image]

I just want to restore the black area with the original image.

Comment: Why would you wanna do that in first place ?

Comment: I want to remove hair from skin lesion images, I did certain blurring and filtering and converted the image to binary. So I want to load the original image without hair.

Comment: Cam you upload the binary image and original image, A lot of things depend upon the format of your binary image, whether foreground is white and background is white or it is other way around.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to *convert* anything, you want to use one image to *mask* another.

Comment: I want to obtain the original region which was present in the black area of the binary image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, but your mask is the wrong size (200x200 px) so it doesn't match your image (600x450 px):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open the input image as numpy array
npImage=np.array(Image.open("image.jpg"))
# Open the mask image as numpy array
npMask=np.array(Image.open("mask2.jpg").convert("RGB"))

# Make a binary array identifying where the mask is black
cond = npMask<128

# Select image or mask according to condition array
pixels=np.where(cond, npImage, npMask)

# Save resulting image
result=Image.fromarray(pixels)
result.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes like this but I wanted the hair removed.

Comment: Mmmm... if you are doing all the heavy-duty image processing in OpenCV (rather than in NumPy like I did), I would suggest you improve the mask there so that it conceals the hairs, then use my code.

Answer (score 7):

As I know binary images are stored in grayscale in opencv values 1-->255.

To create „dummy“ RGB images you can do: 
`rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(binary_img, cv.CV_GRAY2RGB)`

I call them „dummy“ since in these images the red, green and blue values are just the same.

Comment: I have used PIL for binarization and opencv for filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I updated [the Daniel Tremer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50595966/5595995):

```
import cv2
opencv_rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(opencv_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

`opencv_image` would be two dimension matrix like [width, height] because of binary.
`opencv_rgb_img` would be three dimension matrix like [width, height, color channel] because of RGB.